# Which type of distribution is associated with a continuous variable that can take values between zero and a constant?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, continuous-data, uncertainty

I'm working in descriptive statistics of a variable that is the duration of an animal's response given an 8 s interval window. Thus, this variable is bounded between 0 and 8 s. I want to estimate confidence intervals of my data (small sample) using R, but I don't know which distribution would be suitable for modeling this variable.

Comment: If you're not sure of the distribution just bootstrap the confidence interval.

Comment: Even if my sample size is as small as 6? I heard that bootstrapping does not work for samples smaller than 9. However, I'm not sure if this is applicable only for inferential statistics and not for descriptives.

Comment: Yeah that's really small. It's hard to infer much with so few samples imo.

Comment: you could use CIs based on a t-statistic with 4 df and truncate them at {0,8}. If you describe what you're doing clearly enough, readers will know to take the CIs with a big grain of salt.  If you had much more data you could fit something like a censored Gamma or log-Normal distribution ...

Comment: So, @Chris, would you endorse bootstrapping for estimating uncertainty (confidence intervals) in a sample as small as that?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't endorse using a data set that small.

Comment: There are two issues: (a) continuous probability distribution on $(0,8),$ (b) current small sample size. I agree it would be difficult to use fewer than 10 observations to choose a particular model. For (a) beta distributions have support $(0,1)$ and 'generalized beta distributions' are linear transforms of these to get support in any finite interval. If you get more data, you might google 'generalized beta'.

Comment: The simple direct answer: any distribution truncated at zero and constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't know the distribution, you might find it useful to use the nonparametric CI
for the population median that is optional output of the procedure `wilcox.test` in R.

**Uniform Data:**  Below is a 90% CI based on fake data uniformly generated in $(0, 8).$

```
set.seed(730)         # retain 'set.seed' for same fake data; omit for fresh data
x = sort(round(runif(6, 0 ,8),3));  x   # six indep obs from UNIF(0,8)
[1] 1.418 1.609 1.942 2.081 4.169 6.420     

wilcox.test(x, mu=4, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.90)

       Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 6, p-value = 0.4375
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 4
90 percent confidence interval:
 1.6090 4.2505
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
        2.7935
```

A 90% CI for the population median is $(1.6090, 5.2505).$  With $n = 6$ uniformly distributed observations, if
you ask for a 95% CI, then you will usually get the max and min of the six observations
as the CI. 
[The argument `mu = 4` is so the null hypothesis will be that the population median = 4. This
is not necessary, but keeps the 'test' part of the output from being nonsense.]

**Asymmetrical beta data:** For six observations from a generalized beta distribution with shape parameters $\alpha = 1,\, \beta=3$ and with support $(0, 8),$ the data will tend to cluster near the lower end of the support, with population median about 1.65.
The 90% CI from the Wilcoxon test procedure is $(0.8805, 2.8700).$

```
set.seed(731);  y = sort(round(8*rbeta(6, 1, 3),3)); y
[1] 0.577 1.058 1.184 1.546 2.870 3.941

wilcox.test(y, mu=1.65, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.90)

...
90 percent confidence interval:
 0.8805 2.8700
...
```